# How to create a DataFrame with random sample from list?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a list named list1

```
  list1 = ['Banana','Apple','Pear','Strawberry','Muskmelon','Apricot','Peach','Plum','Cherry','Blackberry','Raspberry','Cranberry','Grapes','Greenapple','Kiwi','Watermelon','Orange','Lychee','Custardapples','Jackfruit','Pineapple','Mango']
```

I want to form a df with specific columns and random data from list1

Eg:

```
        a          b       c            d            e         f
   0  Banana    Orange   Lychee     Custardapples Jackfruit  Pineapple
   1   Apple    Pear   Strawberry   Muskmelon    Apricot    Peach
   2  Raspberry Cherry  Plum           Kiwi        Mango   Blackberry
```

A structure something like this but with random data from list1?
There can't be any duplicate/repeated values present.

Comment: Could you please add sample items in each column from your list, so it will be more clear?

Comment: updated with random data for reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If every item from the list can end up everywhere in the `DataFrame` you could write:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list1, 3*6, replace=False).reshape(3, 6), columns=list("abcdef"))

Out: 
        a           b           c          d              e          f
0  Lychee       Peach     Apricot       Pear           Plum     Grapes
1  Cherry   Jackfruit  Blackberry  Cranberry           Kiwi      Apple
2  Orange  Greenapple  Watermelon     Banana  Custardapples  Raspberry
```

The `replace`-parameter in [`np.random.choice()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy-random-choice) is `True` by default, so for unique values you need to set it to `False`.

Comment: Great, it's in a single line.

Comment: Thanks @Darkonaut. what should be done if item can be present once in a df. In above example item 'Watermelon' came thrice. How to make it only once.

Comment: @Zanthoxylumpiperitum Set `choice(...replace=False)` then, it's `True` by default.